# Change variable from multiple sheets?

Tags: excel

I have an excel workbook with multiple sheets that aggregate costs and revenues of different technological components (set up in different sheets) in a system.

I want to have a main worksheet, where users can change a small selection of important variables from the technology sheets. I also want those important variables to be defined and editable on the technology sheets.

I've been using named ranges to manage variables, but I'm not sure how to link two cells on different sheets to one variable. For example, I want to name a variable "oilprice" that is referenced in different formulas. I want to be able to change the variable "oilprice" from the main worksheet and the electricity technology sheet in my workbook.

Similarly, I want to be able to check a box on both sheets for "Turn on Electricity" and have the checkbox on the other sheet change as well.

I've been looking around on google and stackoverflow but can't find an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Named range, option 1: "override" style formula

With named ranges, you are not able to update the value from multiple cells.  You could use logic in a formula to look at a "override" cell and pass that value to the actual named range.  This works if the number of overrides is small.  That style of formula looks like:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(oilprice2), oilprice1, oilprice2)
```

Where `oilprice1` and `oilprice2` are the cells that hold possible values.  Note that there is an implied order in these which can get confusing after a while.  That is, if `oilprice2` has a value, it will not change `oilprice1` nor will `oilprice1` be considered.

[image: named range override]

### Named range, option 2: scroll bar or spin control

Another option similar to the checkboxes below, is to use a spin control or scrollbar control to update the values.  Those work across multiple sheets.

### Checkboxes across sheets

For the checkboxes, this is handled by the `Cell Link`.  You can set as many checkboxes as you want to control a single cell's value.

Here is an example with two checkboxes sharing the same `Cell Link = $C$2`.  They both change when one is clicked.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The checkboxes solution works great!

The named ranges solution doesn't quite solve my issue. It will be confusing for the user if there are different oil prices on different sheets that aren't consistent. I'd rather just have one editable cell and have the other cell report the value in the editable cell. Let me look into the spin control....

Comment: @greg44289, If you want just one editable cell, you can simply name that one.  All other cells can then refer to it w/ `=oilprice`.  Those secondary cells though cannot be changed in a way that back propagates.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out how to have two cells to refer to the same value.

I named a range "oilprice" on the "electricity" sheet.

The cell to input oilprice on the "main" sheet has the formula "=oilprice" and is named "oilprice2", showing the value on the "electricity" sheet "oilprice" named range.

Then I made the following vba code which updates the "oilprice" cell on the electricity sheet when you change the "oilprice2" cell on the main sheet and reverts back to the formula showing "oilprice":

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("oilprice2")) Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
Worksheets("electricity").Range("oilprice").Value = _
    Worksheets("main").Range("oilprice2").Value
Worksheets("main").Range("oilprice2").Value = "=oilprice"
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This approach can leave you vulnerable if macros are not enabled, and someone changes the value thinking they are synced.  You may want to check that the correct formula is in place when the workbook opens to correct that (at least it will check the next time macros are enabled).  This code also makes you vulnerable to changes to the names of the named ranges which removes some of their functionality.  Just beware using this type of code in a production setting.  It solves a problem but might create others.

Comment: These are good points. I'll think about the benefits and costs of this approach. Thanks!