# Link several cells' value in Excel

Tags: excel

Is it possible to set different cells to point and alter the same value?

I mean not using in the second cell a simple `=A1`, what I want is that you can change the value from either of them and be reflected in the other one.

This is so I don't need a "Master control" sheet that affects all others rather than being able to alter a value in any sheet and that change affects all.

I thought I saw it once using names but I can't find or figure out how.

Comment: It's certainly possible using VBA, of course, but you're looking for an entirely in-sheet solution?

Comment: Trying to achieve what you are asking with native worksheet functions is the very definition of a [Circular Reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-fix-a-circular-reference-C17488E3-3CBE-4FA8-A6BC-1A6FFA64DB78). VBA can accomplish this with a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event macro. Get started on one and come back to edit your question and include your effort if you run into trouble,

Comment: This is fairly related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579644/change-variable-from-multiple-sheets/29581910#29581910.  OP there implemented a `Worksheet_Change` event to keep things updated.

Answer (score 0):

Say Sheet1 A2 contains `2` and Sheet 2 A2,`5`. Define a name of workbook scope for Sheet1 A2 (say `nOne`) and a formula anywhere in the workbook of:

```
=nOne+nOne
```

should return `4`. Go to  Name Manager from within any sheet, select `nOne` and Edit... to change Refers to: from `1` to `2`, OK, Close and the above formula will then result in `10`.